# how can I get ID of element which I created by js

Tags: javascript, html, css, createelement

wish all of you are fine , in my code below :
the user every time he clicked on element --> #crBtn, a new button should be create with different id (but all have the same className), for example if the user clicked on #crBtn three times that means 3 buttons will appear , now if I clicked on any of these button i want it to change its background-color and at the same time I need its id , how can i do that in js?

```js
var idNum = 0;
  
    
  function crBtn()
  {
  idNum++;
  var button = document.createElement("button");
  button.innerHTML="HERE";
  button.setAttribute("class","name");
  button.setAttribute("id","na"+idNum);
  document.body.appendChild(button); 
  }
```

```css
 .name
{
 background-color: aquamarine;
border: none;
width:300px;
height: 50px;
cursor: pointer;
margin-right: 10px;
margin-bottom:10px;
}
#crBtn
{
width:500px ;
height:60px;
background-color: blue;
border: none;
margin:30px;
color:white;
font-size: 30px;
}
.name:hover
{
background-color: skyblue;
color:aliceblue;
}
```

```html
 <body>
 <button id = "crBtn" onclick="crBtn()">CLICK TO CREATE BUTTONS</button><br>
 </body>
```

Answer (score 0):

Pass `event` to the function. `target` property of the `event` object is your clicked element.

```
<button id = "crBtn" onclick="crBtn(event)">CLICK TO CREATE BUTTONS</button><br>

function crBtn(e){
  console.log(e.target); //e.target is the button element
}
```

Comment: hello , thank you for answer , i don't want the id of #crBtn, i want to get the id of button which has created by function crBtn(){}

Answer (score 0):

The following script defines a delegated click handler, bound to the body element of the document. Different actions are taken depending on which button was clicked.

```js
var idNum = 0;
document.body.onclick=ev=>{
  if (ev.target.id==="crBtn") crBtn()
  else if (ev.target.className==="name") {
    console.log("click on button with ID "+ev.target.id)
    ev.target.style.backgroundColor="red";
  }
}

function crBtn(){
  idNum++;
  var button = document.createElement("button");
  button.innerHTML="HERE";
  button.setAttribute("class","name");
  button.setAttribute("id","na"+idNum);
  document.body.appendChild(button); 
}
```

```css
.name
{
 background-color: aquamarine;
border: none;
width:300px;
height: 50px;
cursor: pointer;
margin-right: 10px;
margin-bottom:10px;
}
#crBtn
{
width:500px ;
height:60px;
background-color: blue;
border: none;
margin:30px;
color:white;
font-size: 30px;
}
.name:hover
{
background-color: skyblue;
color:aliceblue;
}
```

```html
<body>
 <button id="crBtn">CLICK TO CREATE BUTTONS</button><br>
 </body>
```